# Change Background of View in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

In my app I want to change the background of the view to a color based on an integer value. Everything is working fine, except for when the value changes. After executing the method only a part of the view gets updated. After switching out of the application en switching back, the whole view is updated correctly, but how could I do this without switching?

Code for performing background color changes:

```
public void SetColor(int status)
    {
        View colorView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.view1);

        // Find the root view
        View root = colorView.RootView;
        string color = "";
        Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("SetColor: {0}", status));

        switch (status)
        {
            case 1:
                Log.Debug(TAG, "1");
                color = "Red";
                break;
            case 2:
                Log.Debug(TAG, "2");
                color = "Yellow";
                break;
            case 3:
                Log.Debug(TAG, "3");
                color = "Green";
                break;
            case 4:
                Log.Debug(TAG, "4");

                color = "YellowGreen";
                break;
            case 5:
                Log.Debug(TAG, "5");        
                color = "Grey";
                break;
            default:
                Log.Debug(TAG, "6");
                break;
        }
        Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("Color: {0}", color));
        root.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(color));
    }
```

**Edit 1**

The method is called from the Database class and is called when a value changes in the database:

```
void PostgresNotification(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        var fase = e.AdditionalInformation;
        main.SetColor(Convert.ToInt32(fase));
    }
```

Where main is passed in the Database constructor

```
MainActivity main;
public Database(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
            //Shortened for brevity
            main = mainActivity;
    }
```

Constructor is called in MainActivity's OnCreate()

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Shortened for brevity
        db = new Database(this);
    }
```

Problem:

[image: Update problem]

Comment: When and from where is `SetColor()` called? Please update your question and add the callers

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just updated the question

Comment: is postgres notification called on main thread? if not you may want to relay setting color on UI thread to take corrct effect

Comment: Invoking on the UI thread did the trick, thank you for pointing this out! If you post your answer I could give you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the call to update the color is executed on the main UI thread. Your updates are being interrupted and only partially updating because the OS is controlling the thread management.

Use `RunOnUIThread()` from your activity to make this happen. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/System.Action/

This should solve your problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may work;

1. Create a `public static boolean isColorSet`variable and set it to
   `false` by default.
2. Update its value to `true` whenever you want the color to be set.
3. `Import` the variable in the class that contains your activity in
   which you want to change the color.
4. Then, do `if isColorSet` and set your color in the activity whenever
   a touch is detected on any other small activity the user performs.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this was not entirely the problem. Because of multithreading the function was invoked on the wrong thread, causing a partial update of the view.